# combobox не выводит выбранную строчу в datagridview

Tags: c#, ado.net, datagridview, combobox

Нужно при выборе значения в combobox выводило выбранную строчу в datagridview[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код загрузки данных.

```
 if (cbCVD.SelectedIndex == 0)
      { dataRow.code_view_dish = 1;
            }
            else if (cbCVD.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                dataRow.code_view_dish = 2;
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Во первых у вас в if и else if одинаковые условия .
Редактируйте событие SelectionChangeCommitted у combobox.

Comment: а если у меня нет события SelectedValueChanged

Comment: Я исправил редактируйте SelectionChangeCommitted, ищите в Свойства-> События

Comment: и что там прописать?

Comment: Комментарии лучше оформлять комментариями, а не ответами